# DataList Items.Count Not Working inside UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, datalist

How can I get the total number of items in ASP.NET datalist ?

I have a DataList inside RadAjaxPanel and a submit button outside the panel

and calling this code in the onclick submit always returns 0

```
myDataList.Items.Count
```

I also have tried this, but the same result:

```
DataList myList = RadAjaxPanel1.FindControl("listImages") as DataList;
```

myList still has no items

I also tried to set

```
UseSubmitBehavior="false"
```

for the submit button, but same result

Comment: Are you absolutely positively sure there *are* items in it?

Comment: Yes I am, the photos are displayed in the datalist.

Comment: How and where are you databinding the datalist?

Comment: I am binding it after a file is uploaded, then the photos are displayed in the datalist, and after that I click the submit button and the datalist have no items.

Comment: the datalist is inside an AjaxPanel, can be that a problem?